# Android getting NULL data sent in SERVICE with putExtra in activity

Tags: android, android-intent

in own service i want to send data with intent but i am getting null from Activity.I have read about document from this solution but i can not resolve the problem.

SERVICE :

```
    public void notifyTest(int unread){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, YourDialog.class);
        i.putExtra("data", unread);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity ( i );
    }
```

get data from Activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent ();
    String count = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

i can not use BroadCostReceiver to resolve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**unread** is int then :

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("data",0);
```

**unread** is String then :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this error happened because your data is `int`, but you want to receive it as `String`.

Try to change it like this :

```
public void notifyTest(int unread){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, YourDialog.class);
    i.putExtra("data", unread + ""); //convert to STRING
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity ( i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to "put"

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
```

String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```html
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

Comment: i get `NULL` but `STRING_I_NEED` must be `1`

Comment: that say that you are using int so need to convert it to string using tostring() .just use unread.tosting()